# SQL conflict between collation

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have this error `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.` and i cannot resolve this

**Code is listed Below:**

```
SELECT *
FROM [LinhaRI] LR
WHERE IDdocumento IN
(
    SELECT st.design COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    FROM [admnappl001].[cebi1].[dbo].[st] st
    WHERE st.ststamp = LR.STstamp_Artigo
);
```

Comment: we can't either because there's no code in your question

Comment: I would suggest you changing collation of the column (alter column .. collate) in a way that all character fields have the same collation. Fixing comparison operators is not the best solution.

Comment: @Irdis That might not be an option: `admnappl001` is a linked server and we might have no control over collation there and have reasons not to change it on the local server too.

Comment: yes they have, because i already use the similar code in the pass and work fine, i only change the name of the database and the field

Answer (score 0):

Right up your street: [Difference between collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and Latin1_General_CI_AS](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/rocks/2012/01/09/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as/)

You have a collation conflict when comparing

```
[LinhaRI].[STstamp_Artigo] to [admnappl001].[cebi1].[dbo].[st].[ststamp]
or
[LinhaRI].[IDdocumento]    to [admnappl001].[cebi1].[dbo].[st].[design]
```

You need to check collation on all the columns involved. Your can try to enforce it on every comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM [LinhaRI] LR
WHERE IDdocumento COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS IN
(
    SELECT st.design COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    FROM [admnappl001].[cebi1].[dbo].[st] st
    WHERE st.ststamp = LR.STstamp_Artigo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
);
```

Comment: When i use yoour code occurs one error, just like this "Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause."

Comment: @ThiagoSchettiniMari What are the types of [STstamp_Artigo], [ststamp], [IDdocumento], [design]  fields?

Comment: the [IDdocumento], [STstamp_artigo] and [ststamp] is integer and the [design] is string

Comment: @ThiagoSchettiniMari How come you have `int [IDdocumento] IN str [design]` ? It would seem you can just `CAST(st.design AS INT)` and avoid any collation-related issues altogether.

Comment: because then belong to a same table, the IDdocumento is a PK and the design is a name of the item

Comment: @ThiagoSchettiniMari You have `... WHERE IDdocumento IN (SELECT st.design ...`. That's comparing integer to a string. Maybe what you actually want is `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT st.design FROM [admnappl001].[cebi1].[dbo].[st] st WHERE st.ststamp = LR.STstamp_Artigo);` ?